# Generate a random number without repeating a previous number

Tags: javascript

I need to generate a random number without repeating a previous number. This is my code:

```
getRandomInt( max:number, min:number ) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

It gives me the generated random number but keeps repeating the same number.

Example:

```
1,2,3,4,4
```

and in the second call:

```
1,12,3,14,15
```

Comment: First of all, this answer has nothing to do with Angular. Then, could you please elaborate on what's the input you're giving to your function? How many times are you calling it? Is there a maximum number of generations? Either way, if don't want to repeat previous numbers, you need to store them somewhere and compare each generation.

Answer (score 0):

You could easely do this:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'shuffle', {
    value: function() {
        for (let i = this.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
            [this[i], this[j]] = [this[j], this[i]]
        }
        return this
    }
})
```

```js
var numArray = Array.from(Array(10).keys()) //generate an array with number from 0 to 10
numArray.shuffle()
```

the `.shuffle()` method will randomly take one at a time off the array and print it out.

Comment: How does this prevent repeat numbers?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i actually updated the answer defining the frunction and actually preventing it from repeating numbers